# The objective is to prevent subject/user learning from memory, do you understand what that is?

Tags: java, mergesort

Attached is developed merge sort code that is able to count comparisons made for a given array and print out each comparison. I want it to be able to prevent user learning effectively, so that the numbers compared are spaced out enough in which one would not remember seeing the past numbers as well. Now we need to make it do those comparisons in a different order. The code will probably no longer be pretty and recursive, but some giant ugly loops, I anticipate.

```
public class MyMergeSort {
   private int[] array; //array declared
   private int[] tempMergArr; //temporary array
   private int length; //counting length of array
   private int ncompare=0;

   public static void main(String a[]){

    int[] inputArr = {9, 2, 56, 5, 4, 6, 60, 8, 1, //the array, given 60
            32, 21, 12, 42, 57, 15, 16, 50, 18, 19,
            20, 11, 34, 23, 48, 25, 26, 27, 51, 29,
            30, 31, 10, 33, 22, 35, 39, 37, 38, 36,
            40, 41, 13, 43, 44, 53, 46, 47, 24, 49,
            17, 28, 52, 45, 54, 55, 3, 14, 58, 59,
            7};

    MyMergeSort mms = new MyMergeSort(); //declaring the merge sort for the array
    mms.sort(inputArr);
    System.out.print("\n\n");
    for(int i:inputArr){
        System.out.print(i);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n Number of comparisons "+mms.ncompare+"\n");
}

public void sort(int inputArr[]) { //sort method uses 'this' for array input
    this.array = inputArr; 
    this.length = inputArr.length;
    this.tempMergArr = new int[length];
    doMergeSort(0, length - 1);
}

private void doMergeSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) { //indexed method for merge sort, states each step and case

    if (lowerIndex < higherIndex) {
        int middle = lowerIndex + (higherIndex - lowerIndex) / 2;
        // Below step sorts the left side of the array
        doMergeSort(lowerIndex, middle);
        // Below step sorts the right side of the array
        doMergeSort(middle + 1, higherIndex);
        // Now merge both sides
        mergeParts(lowerIndex, middle, higherIndex);
    }
}

private void mergeParts(int lowerIndex, int middle, int higherIndex) { //merge method using 'for' case,

    for (int i = lowerIndex; i <= higherIndex; i++) {
        tempMergArr[i] = array[i];
    }
    int i = lowerIndex; //declaring index variables for different cases
    int j = middle + 1;
    int k = lowerIndex;
    while (i <= middle && j <= higherIndex) { //define loops for steps of different cases
        System.out.print("   C "+i+" "+j);
        ncompare=ncompare+1;
        if (tempMergArr[i] <= tempMergArr[j]) {
            array[k] = tempMergArr[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            array[k] = tempMergArr[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i <= middle) {
        array[k] = tempMergArr[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

C 0 1
C 2 3
C 0 2
C 1 2
C 1 3

these are the first five comparisons made in my existing algorithm. I want to prevent it from comparing 0 and 2 and then 1 and 2, since the user will likely remember the 2, just like when comparing 1 and 2 and then 1 and 3 the user will remember the 1.

i want to make it so that the numbers compared would not be as memorable to the user as possible, so as to prevent them from making biased comparisons

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking here...

Comment: looking for an algorithm which can sort an array by unordered comparision like
C 0 1 C 2 3 C 0 2 C 1 2 C 1 3

these are the first five comparisons made in my existing algorithm. I want to prevent it from comparing 0 and 2 and then 1 and 2, since the user will likely remember the 2, just like when comparing 1 and 2 and then 1 and 3 the user will remember the 1.

i want to make it so that the numbers compared would not be as memorable to the user as possible, so as to prevent them from making biased comparisons

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clicking for me.  The machine is doing the sort, not an end user.  The "unordered" part is throwing me off even more.

Comment: It is a project which prevents user learning from memory. 
So the repetition of same numbers are not appropriate

Comment: I should be explicit.  **You are _not_ doing a good job of being concise on what the issue is with your code, nor are you being concise on what your ultimate goal is.**  I implore you to update your question to be as clear as possible.  I genuinely can't decipher your requirements no matter how hard I try.

Comment: If you don't want a human user to glean information from the program's output, then the most reliable alternative would be to produce no output.  There is absolutely no point to producing output that is supposed to be meaningless / undecipherable.

Comment: In the question, I've used mergesort algorithm which compares the elements of particular indexes like as

C 0 1      C 2 3       C 0 2       C 1 2      C 1 3 

 I want to prevent it from comparing 0 and 2 and then 1 and 2, since the user will likely remember the 2, just like when comparing 1 and 2 and then 1 and 3 the user will remember the 1. i want to make it so that the numbers compared would not be as memorable to the user as possible, so as to prevent them from making biased comparisons

Comment: "Not memorable to the user" is a difficult-to-understand requirement. Can you explain why the user is trying to memorize the indexes used in each comparison during a merge sort, and why they must be stopped?

Comment: Actually I'm developing an app in which I've to use that kind of prgram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of comparisons is defined by the merge sort algorithm. If you're comparing indexes in an unpredictable or "not memorable" order, you aren't doing merge sort anymore. You'd literally have to invent a new sort algorithm to get this behavior.

However, you could *print* the comparisons in a random order after doing them normally. Just store them in a list field, then shuffle and print them after the sort. For example:

```
public List<int[]> comparisons = new ArrayList<>();
```

Replace the print in `mergeParts` with:

```
comparisons.add(new int[] { i, j });
```

After the sort:

```
mms.sort(inputArr);
Collections.shuffle(mms.comparisons);
for (int[] c : mms.comparisons) {
    System.out.print("   C "+c[0]+" "+c[1]);
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution.